# How to create Spinner-list using CustomAdapter in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

in my app,I want to create SpinnerList using CustomAdapter class,For this i wrote below code but when I tap on spinner list then array-List images are not loading in spinner-list as like my below screen why this problem is coming?

### main_layout.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Category:"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
            "Banana", "Orange", "Hello" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4 };

    Spinner spinner;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {

            RowItem item = new RowItem(titles[i],images[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.listitems_layout, R.id.title, rowItems);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

### listitems_layout.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:text="Strawberry"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### CustomAdapter:-

```
package com.example.venkat.spinnerexample1;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    LayoutInflater flater;

     public CustomAdapter(Activity context,int resouceId, int textviewId, List<RowItem> list){

    super(context,resouceId,textviewId, list);
    flater = context.getLayoutInflater();
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        View rowview = flater.inflate(R.layout.listitems_layout,null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return rowview;
    }
}
```

### RowItem:-

```
package com.example.venkat.spinnerexample1;

public class RowItem {

    private int ImageId;
    private String Title;

    public RowItem(String Title,int ImageId){

        this.Title = Title;
        this.ImageId = ImageId;
    }

    public String getTitle(){

        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title){

        this.Title = Title;
    }

    public int getImageId(){

        return ImageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int ImageId){

        this.ImageId = ImageId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Title ;
    }
}
```

screen:-
---[image]

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView this is exception

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Inside your adapter constructor, send the id of textview also

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity context,int resouceId, int textviewId, List<RowItem> list){

        super(context,resouceId,textviewId, list);
        flater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }
```

call it by

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.listitems_layout, R.id.title, rowItems);
```

**EDIT** 
Your images are not showing because you didn't override the getDropdownView() method. This method decides the layout of child when dropdown is visible. So add this method to your adapter

```
@Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = flater.inflate(R.layout.list_itemslayout,parent, false);
            }
            RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
            return convertView;
        }
```

**Suggestion** 
in your getView() put a check for (convertview == null). It might not have any impact on this small adapter but in case your adapter is having more items, it will impact the performance.

**EDIT**
To put your spinner dropdown below the anchor, use

`android:overlapAnchor="false"` inside your spinner

Comment: i updated ur code but images are not loading from array-List

Comment: ok ok only images not loading from arraylist that's my problem

Comment: hi did u check problem?

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: means when i tapped on spinner button then spinner list have to show below of that title i hope u understand

Comment: yes yes but i want to show spinner list like below of that  spinner title

Comment: android:overlapAnchor="false"

Comment: actually i am begginer for android when i click button then process is same for showing spinner list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106222/discussion-between-ankit-aggarwal-and-abhiram).

Answer (score 40):

Change your adapter like this

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    LayoutInflater flater;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, int resouceId, int textviewId, List<RowItem> list){

        super(context,resouceId,textviewId, list);
//        flater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return rowview(convertView,position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return rowview(convertView,position);
    }

    private View rowview(View convertView , int position){

        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        viewHolder holder ;
        View rowview = convertView;
        if (rowview==null) {

            holder = new viewHolder();
            flater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowview = flater.inflate(R.layout.listitems_layout, null, false);

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            rowview.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (viewHolder) rowview.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        return rowview;
    }

    private class viewHolder{
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Legacy View Holder pattern ;D Vote up

Answer (score -2):

We can also use ViewHolder Pattern

```
public class TypeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
    public TypeAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Calendar> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.calendar_type_row, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return rowView(convertView, position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return rowView(convertView, position);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Views
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //Init Views by itemView.findViewById
        }
    }

    private View rowView(View convertView, int position) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.calendar_type_row,null);
        }
        RowItem rowType = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        //Setup Values
        return convertView;
    }
}
```