# How to remove spinner title?

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am using spinner in android action bar and want to display some items.But that spinner background has image.When I add list of item in spinner.By default first value displays near to the image.Is there any way to remove that by default text.

My spinner code is :

```
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
            android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"/>
```

array/spinnerItems :

```
    <string-array name="spinnerItems">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
        <item>item4</item>
    </string-array>
```

Please find the attached image for reference :

[image]

I want to remove the text "item1" displayed near to action overflow image icon.

Comment: add 1 new item and than value assign blank

Comment: @DarjiJigar Thanks It is the best answer.But some extra space will be displayed in spinner.Can we remove that gap .

Comment: how did you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>
      (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, 
      @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            // this part is needed for hiding the original view
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Comment: you must create custom adapter extend array adapter you can see this answer create custom adapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In layout XML for Spinner use `android:prompt=""`

```
 <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
            android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"/>
```

Or

add first item of spinner like

```
<item>""</item>
```

and promt string also should be

```
 <item>""</item>
```

Comment: I have tried this android:prompt="" but it is prompting some error Error:(35, 32) String types not allowed (at 'prompt' with value '').

Comment: ok try with `android:prompt="@string/prompt"` and set it to null in strings.xml.

Comment: Also you can try second option if first is not working. @vimalmishra

Comment: Yeah Second one solved the issue but problem is in drop down list there are some free space available.But it is working fine with no issues.