# json parsing issues with spinners

Tags: php, android, json

I am getting some data by using php api and i am using JSON PARSING TO GET OUTPUT: BELOW IS THE CODE

```
    private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    state_ids=ParseJSON.ids;
    states=ParseJSON.names;
    //state_nid=ParseJSON.name_nid;

    //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the state list
    ArrayAdapter a3 = new ArrayAdapter(UpdateUserProfile.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states);
    a3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
    state_spin.setAdapter(a3);

}
```

here is parseJson()

```
    protected void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

        ids = new String[users.length()];
        names = new String[users.length()];
        name_nid = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            ids[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
            names[i] = jo.getString(KEY_NAME);
            name_nid[i]=ids[i]+"  "+names[i];
             /*int d=1;
            String e=String.valueOf(d);*/
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the challenging thing for me is that whenever user will select any of the states i want to get the corresponding 'PHP Id' of that state. So that i can send another request to server in order to get the regions of that state. i am displaying corresponding regions on another spinner.

```
     //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {

    selected_state= (String)state_spin.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //state_id_only=selected_state.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    //Log.d("state id is", state_id_only);
    //sendRequest1();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

But on the 'state' spinner i only want to show states text not the ids. So what is the possible solution for this
I hope someone will understand my point and help me... i am a fresher..Thank you

Comment: you need to study about custom spinners

Comment: @VivekMishra can u suggest me any useful link regarding custom spinners? the information i have found about customization was not helpful.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android

Comment: @VivekMishra thank you sir for that link.. i customized my spinner and hide the 'ID' value that i dun wanna show on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @VivekMishra in comments. i used that link and customized my spinner. Then i hide the visibility of ID textView so that in output i can get values of ID textview and due to visibility set its text will not appear in spinner output.