# How can I pass object to the spinner in android?

Tags: java, android, spinner

The code is:

```
public class Organization {

private String name;
private Long id;

public Organization(){
}

public Organization(String name, Long id) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

The spinner is:

```
 Spinner sp = (Spinner) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.brand_spinner).getActionView();
 sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,contactList));
 sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),""+value+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 });
```

How can I pass both name and id to the spinner and the should be listed in the spinner, by selecting the name in the spinner. Store the id of the name in the local variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list

Comment: Custom adapter is required for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own Custom Adapter class which will extend `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` and in that you just pass the `ArrayList<>` of your `Organization`.

Just check this link it will help you in creating adapter

[Check Link](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84)

Answer (score 0):

For ArrayAdapter you are sending contactList, override toString() in objects of contactList. So ArrayAdapter while rendering it will call toString() method each object of contactList to show the text in textView.

So now onClick of item,

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Object obj= parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Contact c = (Contact) obj;
            System.out.println("id = " + c.getId() + " , Name = " + c.getName());

 }
```