# My spinner is still black when i change everything to white, why>

Tags: android, spinner

Like i say. I don't know how to set everything in my `spinner` to white.
Problem is in this image
[image]

Like You see i have white and always black, with black background this button is not good visible.

Here is some code:

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_money"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="50$"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

whats wrong guys?

Here i confgure spinner

```
private void configureSpinnerDataAndLogic() {
    String[] arraySpinner = new String[]{
            "50", "100", "150", "200", "250", "300", "400", "500"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraySpinner);
    spinnerData.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerData.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            String text = spinnerData.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(text);
            text_profit.setText((temp * 2) + " $ " + "100%");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

Edited:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:width="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:height="20dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="135%"
            android:pivotY="15%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: you have to set a custom adapter for spinner

Comment: So much work with this spinner yahahha :D

Comment: i edited my main post

Comment: let me know if you face any issue ..

Comment: yes, please look at code. i create custom from dropdown item and its white, but i can center it

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="center" ` in custom layout

Comment: Still desnt work, look at photo i just can move this. One gravity working is gravity:right

Comment: like a center didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can set the spinners background color in xml like this:

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

and if you are using DropDown then in xml like this:

```
android:popupBackground="@color/your_color_for_items"
```

In case if you are using custom adapter, Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android).

Comment: doesnt help :(((

Comment: @Genehme: I have updated my answer, you need to make changes in your custom adapter. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your Spinner

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

So your final Spinner will look like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, actually. Create a theme that specifies this code in the styles.xml file:

`<style name="MyPickerTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents"> <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item> </style>`

Now just add ' android:theme="@style.MyPickerTheme" ' into your Spinner or any component.