# disable spinner item in XML

Tags: android

I Have a simple spinner and would disable an element.
Could I disable elements from the xml files?
Or i need to code something in JAVA?

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/stato"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview">
</Spinner>
```

arrays.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="feedbacktypelist">
        <item>@string/stato1</item>
        <item>@string/stato2</item>
        <item>@string/stato3</item>
        <item>@string/stato4</item>
        <item>@string/stato5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>

<string name="stato1">ITALIA</string>
<string name="stato2">SPAGNA</string>
<string name="stato3">GERMANIA</string>
<string name="stato4">REPUBBLICA CECA</string>
<string name="stato5">INGHILTERRA</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things, comment out the line in the resource array via highlighting the row and doing `ctrl+/`

or

You can remove the `android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"` line and add the list yourself but skipping the entry you don't want (most common me thinks) see how here [How to create Spinner-list using CustomAdapter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android)