# Android Spinner RealtiveLayout as Item

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-relativelayout

is it possible to set a relativelayout array as items for spinner?

```
RelativeLayout[] items = new RelativeLayout[]{dep1.createObj(getContext()), dep2.createObj(getContext())};
ArrayAdapter<RelativeLayout> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
_deposit.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i'm getting this as an output:

[image]

I would like to use the relativelayout because the object i want to display contains two strings to be displayed with left and right alignment

Comment: You could use a custom spinner adapter and inflate views on it . I don't think passing relative layouts as parameters will work . Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android

Comment: The purpose of the third parameter in the `ArrayAdapter` is because you could you use your own POJO classes or user defined classes to supply the data and use it. Just because it accepts T[] Objects doesn't mean you can pass anything that extends Objects. Use Arrays of Strings or something else which has relevant data and is not an Android component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can only populate `String` in unmodified `ArrayAdapter` with default layout(which is pretty boring).

If you want to change the default behavior, like change the layout like you mentioned above, you have to extend an adapter like `ArrayAdapter`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/7360848) is an example of custom adapter

Comment: Thx a lot. I wrote a custom adapter and it worked out pretty good