# how to show spinner from retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, android-spinner

I have a form using spinner, the data spinner I get from database using retrofit 2 , I have a field `id_fish` and `fish_name`, I would like to show fish_name but id_fish that saved in database.

I success to show the fish_name in android spinner but when i want to save the form into database is `fish_name` , 
how to save `id_fish` while the displayed in spinner is `fish_name`
example as in html :

```
<select>
  <option value="001">Tuna</option>
  <option value="002">Shark</option>
  <option value="003">Dolphin</option>
<select>
```

This is My Function:

```
private initSpinner()
{
List<DataFish> dataFish= response.body().getData();
List<String> idFish = new ArrayList<String>();
                    List<String> fishName = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataFish.size(); i++){

                        idFish.add(dataFish.get(i).getId_fish());
                        nameFish.add(dataFish.get(i).getFish_name());
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LelangActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameFish);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerFish.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This is spinner SetOnclickListener :

```
spinnerFish.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String fishName= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fish name is unique filed you can search on `dataFish` to get the equal `id`. I mean in `onItemSelected` write something like this:

```
for (DataFish data : dataFish) {
    if (data.getFish_name().equls(fishName) {
       data.getId_fish(); //here is your fish id
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: If your fish name filed is not unique and it's possible that two fish with the same name has the different id, you must implement custom adapter for spinner and in `getDropDownView` method define which fish is selected. for implement custom adapter you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35983176/7135845)