# How to generate a spinner in Android with different background color in each item with Java?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, background-color

I want to generate a spinner in Java for color selection, it should look like this when drops down:

[image]

My Java code now looks like this :

```
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
    String[] colors = new String[]{"[1]", "[2]", "[3]", "[4]", "[5]", "[6]"};
    final List<String> colorsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(colors));
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colorsList) {
      @Override
      public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        Color color = Color.rgb(18,18,218);
        switch(position){
           case 0:
              color = Color.rgb(28,158,218); 
              break;
           case 1:
              color = Color.rgb(218,58,218); 
              break;
           case 2:
              color = Color.rgb(128,18,28); 
              break;
        }
        return view;
      }
    };
```

But now no color is shown, all white. What would be a better way to do it?

Comment: Nice and clean approach will be custom adapter see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983176/how-to-create-spinner-list-using-customadapter-in-android.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `TextView` set `BackgroundColor` to `view`. **Beside this** If you want to colorize the selected view, then you also have to override `getView`. Check below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC3C0AA"));
    }
    else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB5DCE8"));
    }

    return view;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Great, it looks right when drops down, but after I select it, the color is not showing, how to fix ?

Comment: To achieve this you also have to override `getView`. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this :

```
  int itemColor[] = new int[]{Color.rgb(188,108,218),
                              Color.rgb(88,18,218),
                              Color.rgb(18,108,28),
                              Color.rgb(18,108,118),
                              Color.rgb(218,88,218),
                              Color.rgb(138,108,118)};
```

...

```
final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
String[] colors = new String[]{"[1]", "[2]", "[3]", "[4]", "[5]", "[6]"};
final List<String> colorsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(colors));
final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colorsList)
{
  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setBackgroundColor(itemColor[position]);
    return view;
  }
};

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setBackgroundColor(itemColor[position]);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
  {

  }
});
```

Comment: Why you make this complicated instead of my simple solution? Is this make any difference?